# mysql -uroot ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (38) MacOS

Tags: mysql, macos, homebrew, apple-m1, mysql-5.7

I installed mysql on my mac by following below steps.

1. brew install mysql@5.7
2. Added relevent configs to bash progile file
3. brew services restart mysql@5.7
   I got the belwo result

```
Stopping `mysql@5.7`... (might take a while)
==> Successfully stopped `mysql@5.7` (label: homebrew.mxcl.mysql@5.7)
==> Successfully started `mysql@5.7` (label: homebrew.mxcl.mysql@5.7)
```

4. Then tried to connect to the mysql server by using `mysql -uroot`. But I got the below error.

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (38)
```

I verifed the 'tmp' directory and didn't see a 'mysql.sock' file. How can I resolve this behaviour? I did reinstallation multiple time, but it didn't resolve the issue. Please share your opinion to resove this.